# safari flex does not work with clearfix hack

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I added clearfix hack in flex container, which contains float flex item. It works fine with Chrome (version 51.0.2704.84) and Firefox (version 47.0), but doesn't work in Safari (Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17)). The third item will go to second row as well as there has enough room. I am wondering whether it's a bug and how to workaround it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
/* its me who make this magic */
#container:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
#container:after {
  clear: both;
}
#container > div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333333%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>xxx</div>
  <div>ooooo</div>
  <div>nmn</div>
  <div>sdfsdf</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ghwm4ua/8/

Answer (score 1):

Your clearfix code should not work in Safari (or Chrome or Firefox, for that matter).

The `float` and `clear` properties have no impact in a flex container. They are ignored.

*From the specification:*

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> A flex container establishes a new *flex formatting context* for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that flex layout is used instead of block layout.
>
> ***For example, floats do not intrude into the flex container***, and the flex
>   container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents.
>
> Flex containers are not block containers, and so some properties that
>   were designed with the assumption of block layout don’t apply in the
>   context of flex layout. In particular:
>
> - `float` and `clear` do not create floating or clearance of flex item, and don't take it out-of-flow.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand float does not impact flex. I think the purpose of using float is just in case of browser doesn't support flex(i am not sure if i am right)....when div width is set to 33.3333%.it's supposed to have 3 divs each row.but in Safari there are 2 divs each row.  It seems like before pesudo element has impact on flex container...

Comment: I'm observing some similar issues with pseudo :after, when disabling the content property for the clearfix hack - overflow issues disappear, introduce it back and the issues come back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this blogpost had a solution that worked for me:
https://danisadesigner.com/blog/flexbox-clear-fix-pseudo-elements/

The trick mentioned in the post was to give the `:before` element a width of 0 so it's not included in the column calculation (if not it seems to get a value of 1px). Like this:

```
.clear-fix:before,
.clear-fix:after {
  flex-basis: 0;
  order: 1;
}
```